# Validação in_array com Ç

Tags: php

Tenho um array:

```
$enderecos  = array( 'Endereço', 'Endereco', 'Endereço ' );
```

Uso a função `fgetcsv` para ler meus CSV, eu faço a verificação no header do csv comparando se o header está incluso no array.

```
    if(in_array($colunas_csv, $enderecos))
    {
        $endereco_posicao = $key;
    }
```

Onde `$colunas_csv` é o retorno do header, o que ocorre é que se o header retornado for `Endereco` a verificação ocorre, mas, se for `Endereço` não ocorre, devido ao `Ç`.

Comment: Mas o `$colunas_csv` está em UTF-8? Se não, qual é a codificação utilizada?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode se basear nesse exemplo:

```
<?php
        $arr = ["Endereco","Endereço","Não", "Olá"];
        $decode = implode(' ', $arr);
        $Format = array();
        $Format['a'] = 'ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜüÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûýýþÿRr"!@#$%&*()_-+={[}]/?;:.,\\\'<>°ºª'; //Pega tudo que tiver acento
        $Format['b'] = 'aaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnoooooouuuuuybsaaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnoooooouuuyybyRr                                 '; //Todos os itens do Format['b'] vão ser substituidos por esses
        $Data = strtr(utf8_decode($decode), utf8_decode($Format['a']), utf8_decode($Format['b'])); //Faz a substituição
        $Final = trim(strip_tags($Data)); //Limpa a string de espaços iniciais e finais e de codigos html/JS/PHP
        echo $Final;

?>
```

O que vai ser impresso: `Endereco Endereco Nao Ola`

Tentei explicar com comentários pra ficar mais fácil entender.